# Label caption to spinbutton value

Tags: vba, label, caption

I have a problem with loading of value from label caption to spinbutton value and back. I have some data from report, but I need only 6-8 hours from the report, so I made form, where i want to set start time and end time (yyyy,mm,dd hh:mm) and then I want to delete rows, where is not my time, so I am loading year, month, day, hour and minute as Now() to captions, then I need load caption of label to value of spinbutton and then I need change caption to value, like has spinbutton. Thanks for your posts and sorry for my English ;) Here is my code:

```
    Sub spust()

formtime.lblrok1.Caption = Format(Now, "yyyy")
formtime.lblmes1.Caption = Format(Now, "mm")
formtime.lblden1.Caption = Format(Now, "dd")
formtime.lblhod1.Caption = Format(Now, "hh")
formtime.lblmin1.Caption = Minute(Now)

If Len(formtime.lblmin1.Caption) = 1 Then
    formtime.lblmin1.Caption = "0" & Minute(Now)
End If

formtime.lblrok2.Caption = Format(Now, "yyyy")
formtime.lblmes2.Caption = Format(Now, "mm")
formtime.lblden2.Caption = Format(Now, "dd")
formtime.lblhod2.Caption = Format(Now, "hh")
formtime.lblmin2.Caption = Minute(Now)

If Len(formtime.lblmin2.Caption) = 1 Then
    formtime.lblmin2.Caption = "0" & Minute(Now)
End If

With formtime.spbutrok1
    'my problem -> .Value = CInt(formtime.lblrok1.Caption)
    .Min = 2010
    .Max = 2030

End With

formtime.lblrok1.Caption = CStr(formtime.spbutrok1.Value)

formtime.Show
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `SpinButton` can be quite tricky

your problem is due to the fact that default `SpinButton` control bounds are 0 (`Min` property) and 100 (`Max` property) and you're trying to set its `Value` property to some *20XX* number (to which `lblrok1.Caption` has previously been initialized) that clearly exceeds it!

it could seem the solution is postponing that setting:

```
With formtime.spbutrok1
    .Min = 2010
    .Max = 2030
    .Value = CInt(formtime.lblrok1.Caption)
End With
```

but there comes in another `SpinButton` issue:

- to link the `Label` caption to the `SpinButton` value you must code in the userform code pane something like:

  ```
  Private Sub spbutrok1_Change()
      With Me
          .lblrok1.Caption = .spbutrok1.value
      End With
  End Sub
  ```
- on definition of a `SpinButton` bounds if its *current* `Value` isn't already between them then it gets set to the minimum between its *current* `Min` and `Max` values
- if the latter condition applies and causes an *actual* change of the `SpinButton` `Value`) than it'll trigger its 'Change()' event that will change label caption again to a value that is not the one you're expecting

  in your case the result would be both `SpinButton` `Value` and corresponding `Label` `Caption` set to 2010...

so you may want to adopt such a sequence:

```
With formtime.spbutrok1
    .max = 2030'<--| this may trigger SB 'Change()' event handler that, via appropriate event handler coding, changes corresponding label capition accordingly
    .min = 2011'<--| this may trigger SB 'Change()' event handler that, via appropriate event handler coding, changes corresponding label capition accordingly
    .value = Format(Now, "yyyy"),'<-- set SB value to wanted value. And if this results in an actual change of the preceding value, then it'll trigger its 'Change()' event also that changes corresponding label capition accordingly
End With
```

Other than that, date issues (months bounds differ and leap year throws in some more mess) may give you more coding headaches: should that be the case, you may want to make other posts...

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I am begginer, therefore so stupid mistakes ;)